# Word for object of a search

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a noun to describe the object of a search? For example in the sentence: "I was searching for my toothbrush". Is there a word to describe "my toothbrush"?

I am looking for a word along the lines of searchee (but that is not a real word).

Comment: It's usually called "the object of the search"

Comment: "[Searchee](https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=BpTfVMroIMiC8Qe0ooG4BQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=searchee&safe=off&tbm=bks)" is a real word, it is just not that suitable for everyday speech. There is "wanted" along the lines of your question but not a fit for your example. And there is "lost" of course.

Comment: Mission: Search  **Objective**: toothbrush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst not commonly used, the word **[quaesitum](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/quaesitum)** refers to something which is sought.

Answer (score 1):

There is also "[missing](https://www.google.com/search?q=missing&oq=missing&aqs=chrome..69i57.2808j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=missing%20definition&revid=1578333022)"; (of a thing) not able to be found because it is not in its expected place.
"a quantity of cash has gone missing"
synonyms:   lost, mislaid, misplaced, absent, gone (astray), gone, unaccounted for;     not present or included when expected or supposed to be.
"passion was an element that had been missing from her life for too long." 
synonyms:   absent, not present, lacking, wanting
"passion was missing from her life";
(of a person) absent from a place, especially home, and of unknown whereabouts.
"she alerted police that her son was missing"

Answer (score 0):

It would hardly do for a toothbrush but, if the object of your search was of sufficient significance, you could describe it as your "**grail**". [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grail) provides this secondary definition: "the object of an extended or difficult quest."